# Extract the edge between two raster cells with different values

Tags: raster, r

Is there a way in R to create lines (black lines in the figure below) along the edge between two raster cells that have different values ?

[image]

**Update**

I'm trying the functions `clump()` and `rasterToPolygons()` as in the post [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28859181/how-to-get-contour-lines-around-the-grids-in-r-raster].

First, I reclassified my raster "r" to have cells with two different values:

```
new.values <- cbind(c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8), c(NA, NA, 1, NA, 2, NA, NA, NA, NA))
new.r <- reclassify(r, rcl=new.values)
```

Then, I used the functions `rasterToPolygons` and `clump`:

```
test.edge <- rasterToPolygons(clump(new.r), dissolve=TRUE)
plot(test.edge, add=TRUE)
```

And I obtained:

[image]

How can I extract the edges that have not contour lines (for example, edges near red arrows) because they are located between two different values?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/28860137/3338646

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is not wise to mix the `clump(..)` functionality from `igraph` with the `dissolve=TRUE` parameter from the `rasterToPolygon` routine. They both do something with to aggregate the fields together but in a different way. At least we want to do 3 things:

1. read or desing a raster
2. select raster area where the contour goes around
3. define how the contour is shaped (rectangular,linear or smooth) and define which areas belong together.

In the `clump` code raster, the type of raster and the definition of `NA` seems to be important to steer clumping the process. I made some test but with bad results. I followed your sketch and here is a **little** analysis how to get things work:

```
# Load packages
require('raster')
require('rgeos')

# Clean up everything
rm(list=ls())

# Set a defined random seed
set.seed(2)

# Create a float raster with values
# the interval [0,2] float
rs <- raster(nrow=10, ncol=10)

# Scale the random numbers from interval [0,1) to
# to [0,2.2) and shift the interval to [-0.1,2.1)
rs[] <- runif(ncell(rs)) * 2.2 - 0.1

# Cut off the raster values to [0,2]
# Everything smaller then 0 is zero
values(rs)[values(rs) < 0.0] <- 0.0

# Everything larger then 2 is two
values(rs)[values(rs) > 2.0] <- 2.0
```

Is the raster field well constructed?

```
# Construction is OK?
> quantile(values(rs))
       0%       25%       50%       75%      100% 
0.0000000 0.3928834 0.8733250 1.6027794 2.0000000
```

Here is the function prototype that selects the field in the interval `[1,2)`.

```
# Function of the contour ID
inOne <- function(x) { x>=1 & x<2 }

> inOne(0) 
[1] FALSE

> inOne(1) 
[1] TRUE

> inOne(2)
[1] FALSE
```

The contour cannot be dissolved (`clump`) because of the float number nature of the raster field is distinct in the ID process (`dissolve-=TRUE`).

```
# Contour of the float desing
# x := [1,2)
ct <- rasterToPolygons(rs, 
         fun=inOne , 
         dissolve=TRUE) 
plot(rs)
plot(ct, add=TRUE)
```

You see the right contour groups, but polygons are not joint.

[image: Float design]

So if we have a unique ID of each cell as Integer, the dissolve process should work.

```
# Apply integer operation (ceiling, floor, round)
# to the float number fields 
rs.int <- ceiling(rs)
values(rs.int)
ct.int <- rasterToPolygons(rs.int, 
              fun=inOne , 
              dissolve=TRUE) 
plot(rs.int)
plot(ct.int, add=TRUE)
```

[image: Integer desing]

Conclusion: I think (do know not exactly) what behind the `clump` stuff works a raster based region growing routine. The process  `dissolve=TRUE` in the rasterToPolygon (based on [rgeos CRAN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWaY9.png)) seems to follow a vector approach. So I've to read the manuals of `igraph` and `rgeos` carfully.

REM: The selection of contours (float vs. int) differs, because of the nature of (ceiling, floor and round).

Comment: Thank you very much huckfinn for your help. I tested the code but I obtained contour lines around all polygons with cell values that are equal to 1. Is it possible to have the edge between cells with only values that are equal to 1 (yellow) and 2 (green) ? In the second image of your answer, there is edges between cells with values that are equal 1 (yelllow) and 0 (white). I found the function `extractedge` in the software "GME" [http://www.spatialecology.com/gme/extractedge.htm]. The function works very well but I would prefer to use only R.

Comment: Oh, I think thats the part you have to investigate between the selection function  `inOne <- function(x) { x>=X & x<Y }` and the discretization type `rs.int <- ceiling(rs)` (floor, round ..also possible ) and a step wise selection  (layer 1 is inOn() ..layer 2 is inTwo()...) I guess.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to do. I still have the contour lines around polygons and not just the edges between two cells like in my first image.

Comment: Than is the rasterToPolygons not an option to calculate, because polygons **enclose** areas with one states and the rest out side. You want to separate three states A, B and NA.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot not find some stuff in the `raster` and `rgeos` package and wrote a small example that calculates **ONLY** the segments (egdes in `igraph` speech) between two layers from scratch, not very fast. To build lines (topologies) from this point is not a straight forward to handle task. One point can join four segments, if you have a chess board pattern for example. If you connect all segments you will get a line graph not a line string. I think there are better solutions and you could investigate the capabilities of `igraph`.

Here is the script:

```
# Load packages
require('raster')

# ----------------------------------------
# Create a test raster with 
# cell transitions 2 -> 1
# some open cells at the border 
# and 0 hole in the center
makeTestRaster <- function() {
  nc <-5; nr <-5;
  rs<-raster(nrow=nr,ncol=nc);
  for (c in 1:nc) {
    for (r in 1:nr) {
      if( r==2 | c==2 | r==4 | c==4 ) {
        rs[r,c]=2;
      } 
      else if (r==3 | c == 3)  {
        rs[r,c]=1;
      }
      else {
        rs[r,c]=0;
      }
    }
  }
  rs[3,3] <-0
  return(rs)
}

# ----------------------------------------------
# Calculate all segments with a <-> b connection
# (without a iteration pattern)
# df - the serialized form
# rs - the raster
# pos - pos in the table
# a - cell sourrounded by 
# b - cell neighbor type
calcSegmentAtPos <- function(df,rs, pos, a, b, DEBUG=FALSE) {
  nc<-ncol(rs) # number of columns 
  nr<-nrow(rs) # number of rows
  pcol<-(pos-1) %%   nc + 1; # raster col
  prow<-(pos-1) %/%  nc + 1; # raster row
  result<-c(); # result vector
  # Position in raster OK?
  if (pcol <  0 | prow <  0 |
      pcol > nc | prow > nr ) {
    return (result);
  } 
  # Call is of type A
  if (rs[prow, pcol] != a) return (result);
  # Cell resolution x and y
  dx <- xres(rs);
  dy <- yres(rs);
  # Test positions and type (horizontal, vertical)
  tcol  <- c(pcol-1, pcol+1, pcol,   pcol);
  trow  <- c(prow,   prow,   prow-1, prow+1);
  ttype <- c(TRUE,   TRUE,   FALSE,  FALSE);
  # Run tests and calc segments 
  for (ix in 1:4) {
      scol <- tcol[ix] # test column 
      srow <- trow[ix] # test row
      vertical <- ttype[ix]; # generation type
      # Test position in raster OK?
      if (scol < 1 | scol > nc | 
          srow < 1 | srow > nr ) {
        next;
      }  
      # Test type a <-> b between cells OK ?
      va = rs[prow,pcol]
      vb = rs[srow,scol]
      if (rs[prow,pcol] == a &
          rs[srow,scol] == b) {
        # Somcontraol messages if wanted
        if (DEBUG) {
          cat("pcol", pcol, "| prow", prow, 
            "| scol", scol, "| srow", srow,
            "| a",va,"| b",vb,"| vert", vertical,
            "\n")
        }

        dta <- df[pos, ] # get the data row
        x <- dta$x;      # center of the cell X
        y <- dta$y;      # center of the cell Y
        # Vertical segment
        if ( vertical ){
          x1 <- x + (scol-pcol) * dx/2
          x2 <- x1
          y1 <- y - dy/2
          y2 <- y + dy/2
        } 
        # Horizontal segment
        else {
          y1 <- y + (prow-srow)  * dy/2
          y2 <- y1;
          x1 <- x - dx/2
          x2 <- x + dx/2
        }
        # push data to the result vector
        result<-c(result,c(pos,x,y,x1,y1,x2,y2))
      } # in frame an state a b
  }  #iterate test positions
  return (result) 
}

# --------------------------------------------
# Calculate the segments of over all
# raster points of rs with the transtition a,b
calcSegments <- function(rs, a, b) {

  # Serialized form of the raster
  # with all coordinates
  df <- as.data.frame(rs,xy=TRUE)
  # Understand cell addressing 
  nall <- ncell(rs);
  # df$col <- seq(0,nall-1) %%  nc +1
  # df$row <- seq(0,nall-1) %/% nc +1
  #Resulting segment buffer
  segs <- c();
  for (pos in 1:nall) {
    v <- calcSegmentAtPos(df, rs, pos, a, b);
    if (length(v)>0) segs <-c(segs,v)
  }
  # Re-arrange the segment vector into a data frame
  len<-length(segs)/7; sq <-(0:(len-1))*7 # Index sequenz
  return(data.frame(id=segs[sq+1],
                    x=segs[sq+2],
                    y=segs[sq+3],
                    x0=segs[sq+4],
                    y0=segs[sq+5],
                    x1=segs[sq+6],
                    y1=segs[sq+7]))
}

rs <- makeTestRaster()

# Calculate the segments
df <- calcSegments(rs, 2, 1)
```

The result is a segment table could be a start point to use `igraph` to compose a graph.

```
> head(df)
  id    x  y   x0  y0   x1 y1
1  2  -72 72  -36  54  -36 90
2  4   72 72   36  54   36 90
3  6 -144 36 -180  18 -108 18
4  8    0 36  -36  54   36 54
5 10  144 36  108  18  180 18
6 12  -72  0 -108 -18 -108 18
```

- id - index of the raster cell
- x - center of the cell x
- y - center of the cell y
- x0 - start point edge x
- y0 - start point edge y
- x1 - end point edge x
- y1 - end point edge y

The visualisation of the resulting segments looks like this.

```
# Plot the raster
plot(rs);

# Draw the segments
segments(df$x0,df$y0,df$x1,df$y1)

# Draw the center points
points(df$x,df$y)
```

[image: Example]